# Linq to many objects using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to use Linq to create an object which itself contains 2 data objects. From the Linq expression I am trying to set up the objects directly rather than having an inbetween function in the containing class.

The containing class looks like this:

```
public class SupplierCategories
{

    public  category _category;
    public category_sub _category_sub;
    private bool _IsActive;
    private int? _SupplierID;

    public SupplierCategories()
    {

    }

    public bool IsActive
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsActive;
        }
        set
        {
            _IsActive = value;
        }
    }

    public int? SupplierID
    {
        get
        {
            return _SupplierID;
        }
        set
        {
            _SupplierID = value;
            if (_SupplierID != null) // The county is active if there is a supplier ID matching
            {
                _IsActive = true;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Note: category and category_sub objects are all set up through the Entity Framework.

My link expression has 2 tables and looks like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<SupplierCategories> GetAllOrdered()
    {
        IEnumerable<SupplierCategories> areaList;

        var results = from cat in dbContext.categories
                      join sub in dbContext.category_sub on cat.id equals sub.categoryid
                      orderby cat.id ascending, sub.name ascending
                      select new SupplierCategories
                      {
                          _category = { new category { cat.id, cat.name } },
                          _category_sub = { new category_sub { sub.id, sub.categoryid, sub.name } }
                      };

        areaList = results.ToList();

        return areaList;
    }
```

---

Hopefully you can see that I am trying to create the "_category" and "_category_sub" objects directly.

The error I get is:

> Error 5 Cannot initialize type
>   'Essential_Collections.Models.category'
>   with a collection initializer because
>   it does not implement
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerable'
>   D:\Websites\Essential
>   Collections\development\build\Essential
>   Collections\Models\SupplierCategories\SupplierCategoriesRepository.cs
>   51 37 Essential Collections

Any solutions or possibly other approaches would be gratefully received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the extra braces thus:

```
public IEnumerable<SupplierCategories> GetAllOrdered()
{
    IEnumerable<SupplierCategories> areaList;

    var results = from cat in dbContext.categories
                  join sub in dbContext.category_sub on cat.id equals sub.categoryid
                  orderby cat.id ascending, sub.name ascending
                  select new SupplierCategories()
                  {
                      _category = cat,
                      _category_sub = sub
                  };

    areaList = results.ToList();

    return areaList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, works fine. However if I wanted to create objects which didn't directly map to tables could I do something like above specifying individual values?

Comment: @Billyhomebase: @BFree highlights where you were going wrong with your object constructors for category and category_sub. Provided you either have an appropriate constructor or you appropriately identify the properties you are initialising then you can instantiate new objects for those.

Comment: If this "works fine", I'd suggest accepting it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the parantheses on the constructor call:

```
select new SupplierCategories()
{
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerable<SupplierCategories> GetAllOrdered()
{
    IEnumerable<SupplierCategories> areaList;

    var results = from cat in dbContext.categories
                  join sub in dbContext.category_sub on cat.id equals sub.categoryid
                  orderby cat.id ascending, sub.name ascending
                  select new SupplierCategories
                  {
                      _category = new category { cat.id, cat.name } , //removed the curly braces here
                      _category_sub = new category_sub { sub.id, sub.categoryid, sub.name } //removed the curly braces here
                  };

    areaList = results.ToList();

    return areaList;
}
```

The error you're getting is because of those curly braces I removed. This still won't compile because you need to explicitly spell out which property you're setting in the object initializer:

```
_category = new category { ID = cat.id, Name = cat.name }
```

or if your category class has a constructor overload that takes those args, then pass those in.